# The referenced project does not exist - TeamCity

Tags: c#, selenium, msbuild, teamcity

When trying to run a build in TeamCity I'm getting an error.
the main problem is probably in :

> The referenced project '..\Sql_connection\Sql\Sql.csproj' does not exist. [C:\BuildAgent\work\671db445ff5c93f7\ReportAppeal\ReportAppeal.csproj.teamcity]

My main project is ReportAppeal. I have a reference to a duplicate project named Sql. 
ReportAppeal project located just as seen in the error.

> C:\BuildAgent\work\671db445ff5c93f7\ReportAppeal\

while the Sql project located in :

> C:\BuildAgent\work\671db445ff5c93f7\Sql

However, the Sql original project located in my Source Control as well, if it means anything. 
What am I doing wrong? 
By the way, when trying to build from Command Line by using

> Msbuild.exe

I'm gettign the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, there is an error with your checkout rules.

The `./` is `C:\BuildAgent\{Id}\`

Your principal project is at `./ReportAppeal`

Referencing `./Sql_connection\Sql\Sql.csproj`
But, the checkout rule you are describing only get the `./Sql` SubFolder of the `.\Sql_connection` folder.

I think, you don't need to rewrite the folder of Sql_connection when you are trying to checkout it.

Comment: what do you mean by saying I don't need to rewrite it? how would I do that?

Comment: When you are setting your checkout rules, I think you are doing something like: 
`(+:)./Sql_Connection/Sql => ./Sql` this part seems to be the issue.

Comment: I agree that's the issue but I'm not sure I know how to fix it , because originally the Sql's project name is "Sql_connection". I have tried use it as it is , but I had other issue since the csproj file is under "Sql" and not under "Sql_connection"